# Dotfuscator Post-Build Event Exited With Code 1

Tags: .net, build, build-automation, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I am trying to automatically dotfuscate my projects during the build process in TFS.

I have created a "Post-Build Event" under the project properties as follows:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\PreEmptive Solutions\Dotfuscator Professional
>   Edition 4.9\dotfuscator.exe" /in:"$(TargetPath)"
>   /out:"$(TargetDir)Obfuscated\" /honor:on /strip:on /prune:off
>   /rename:off /suppress:on /mapout:"$(TargetFileName).xml" /debug:pdb
>   xcopy /S /R /Y "$(TargetDir)Obfuscated\$(TargetFileName)"
>   "$(TargetDir)"

When this event kicks off I get the following error:

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (3717): The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\PreEmptive
>   Solutions\Dotfuscator Professional Edition 4.9\dotfuscator.exe"
>   /in:"C:\Builds\5\BIMS\Sandbox Branch Private Test Manual
>   Build\Binaries\ProcessBookmarks.exe" /out:"C:\Builds\5\BIMS\Sandbox
>   Branch Private Test Manual Build\Binaries\Obfuscated\" /honor:on
>   /strip:on /prune:off /rename:off /suppress:on
>   /mapout:"ProcessBookmarks.exe.xml" /debug:pdb xcopy /S /R /Y
>   "C:\Builds\5\BIMS\Sandbox Branch Private Test Manual
>   Build\Binaries\Obfuscated\ProcessBookmarks.exe"
>   "C:\Builds\5\BIMS\Sandbox Branch Private Test Manual Build\Binaries\""
>   exited with code 4."

I have done hours of research, experimentation, and googling on this subject and have not been able to figure out explaination for the error.  When I run the build locally the command works just fine.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: 
I have made several more attempts at getting dotfuscator to work via command line.  I have ensured that the dotfuscator command works by itself locally, but when I run the build definition the dotfuscator command line exits with code 1 as follows, and I have no idea how to fix it:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (3717): The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\PreEmptive Solutions\Dotfuscator Professional Edition 4.9\dotfuscator.exe" /in:"C:\Builds\5\BIMS\Sandbox Branch Private Test Manual Build\Binaries\ProcessBookmarks.exe" /out:"C:\Builds\5\BIMS\Sandbox Branch Private Test Manual Build\Binaries\Obfuscated" /honor:on /strip:on /prune:off /enhancedOI:on /suppress:on /mapout:"C:\Builds\5\BIMS\Sandbox Branch Private Test Manual Build\Binaries\ProcessBookmarks.exe.xml" /debug:pdb" exited with code 1.

I am still having trouble with getting dotfuscator to work in my automated builds, does anyone have an example of how they are doing it.  I would really appreciate an answer to this question.

Comment: Can you share what is shown in your Output Window?

Comment: I have removed the xcopy command and tried running just the dotfuscator command.  The command works locally and correctly dotfuscates the file and puts it in the correct folder, however when I run the actual build definition I get an exited with code 1 now.  There is no additional information that I can see available in the build log file or output window to share.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using copy rather than xcopy to copy your obfuscated dlls to your output folder.

The reason I suggest this is because I have spent the day trying to do the same as you, except I have Dotfuscator projects (*.dotfuproj) in my solution (rather than calling Dotfuscator via the commandline in the post build step) and I was trying to copy the Dotfuscator output during the Dotfuscator projects post build step.

When I used xcopy it failed to copy the file with no warning, error or message of any sort. It just continued like nothing happened - no positive or negative output. Nothing.

Executing the xcopy command via the command line worked fine - nothing made sense as to why xcopy did not work and why I got no message indicating why. [If anyone know why this is I would love to know]

With copy you need to specify the destination file rather than just the directory as you have above in your xcopy command.

[I would have added this as a comment to your question but I don't appear to have the ability/rep(?)]

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response.  I have since moved on to several other solutions, none of them ideal.  I will try and go in and see if this fixes the issue.  Thanks a lot!